# Formula error in syntax

Tags: formula, formula-field

I am trying to use a formula field where we are using IF statement but I am getting an error that it should have 3 return type and received two.

```
IF(CONTAINS("Re-Admit, re admit, readmit,Readmit,Re admit,ReAdmit,Re admit,Re-admit", TEXT(LastName), "1",
IF(CONTAINS("Re-Admit 2 , re admit 2, readmit 2,Readmit 2,Re admit 2,ReAdmit 2,Re admit 2,Re-admit 2",TEXT(LastName), "2"),

IF(CONTAINS("Re-Admit 3 , re admit 3, readmit 3,Readmit 3,Re admit 3,ReAdmit 3,Re admit 3,Re-admit 3",TEXT(LastName), "3"),"")
```

Comment: Please note, formulae is plural and formula is singular. When you are talking about one instance, it is a formula, not a formulae.

Answer (score 2):

Your parentheses are wrong in several places. Proper indentation can make these errors more clear:

```
IF(
    CONTAINS(
        "Re-Admit...",
        LastName // <-- remove TEXT(...) call if this is a text field
    ), // <-- missing closing parenthesis added
    1, // <-- if your return type is Number, don't wrap the return value in quotes
    IF(
        CONTAINS(
            "Re-Admit 2...",
            LastName // <-- remove TEXT(...) call if this is a text field
        ), // <-- missing closing parenthesis added
        2, // <-- extra closing parenthesis removed
        // ^^^ if your return type is Number, don't wrap the return value in quotes
        IF(
            CONTAINS(
                "Re-Admit 3...",
                LastName // <-- remove TEXT(...) call if this is a text field
            ), // <-- missing closing parenthesis added
            3, // <-- extra closing parenthesis removed
            // ^^^ if your return type is Number, don't wrap the return value in quotes
            0 // <-- if your return type is Number, your fallback value should be 0 or null
        ) // <-- close third IF formula
    ) // <-- close second IF formula (added)
) // <-- close first IF formula (added)
```

I believe the first `CONTAINS` check will actually catch all the values from the subsequent checks, so you should also reverse the order, checking the `"1"` case last.

---

After reviewing the comments, nearly every single clause you implement has an error. It may be more legible to list them here:

- Your `IF` syntax needs to be `IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)`.
- Your `CONTAINS` syntax needs to be `CONTAINS(text, compare_text)`.
- Composing these functions should yield `IF(CONTAINS(text, compare_text), value_if_true, value_if_false)`
- Composing three nested `IF` statements should yield `IF(condition1, value_if_condition1, IF(condition2, value_if_condition2, IF(condition3, value_if_condition3)))`
- You can't call `TEXT` on a field that is already of the type Text.
- To return a number, use values like `1` instead of `"1"`.
- The value `""` is not a valid number. Use `0` or `null` instead.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I have choosen number as return type on formulae field but I get an error : Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Incorrect parameter type for function 'TEXT()'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, Picklist, received Text (Related field: Formula) . I have used the formulae as :

Comment: You can likely remove the `TEXT` function entirely. I thought that was weird...you would only do that if it were a picklist, not if it's a Text field. Also if the return type is Number, you need to remove the quotes around the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF( CONTAINS( "Re-Admit:re admit:readmit:Readmit:Re admit:ReAdmit:Re Admit:Re-admit", LastName),
    IF( CONTAINS( " 2", LastName),
        2,
        IF( CONTAINS( " 3", LastName),
            3,
            1
        )
    ),
null)
```

Comment: Hi When I try to use the above formulae when the return type is number on the field, the formulae does not check the syntax but does gets saved. Also I get blank in the result. please let me know the return type field I should be using

Comment: Does you last name value contains any from the values that formulas is validating? It returns null (blank) if it doesn't contain any.

Comment: LastName = Prakash readmit,

LastName = Prakash readmit2

Lastname = Prakash readmit3

Answer (score 0):

I have also used the formulae IF( CONTAINS( "Re-Admit:re admit:readmit:Readmit:Re admit:ReAdmit:Re Admit:Re-admit", LastName), IF( CONTAINS( " 2", LastName), 2, IF( CONTAINS( " 3", LastName), 3, 1 ) ), null)

but it shows blank value.

The last name has values mentioned as : LastName = Prakash readmit,
LastName = Prakash readmit2
Lastname = Prakash readmit3